# How to add highlights or descriptions to the Unity Editor interface

Tags: unity

Is there a way to develop a Unity learning program that runs within the Unity Editor?

For example, I want to create something like a highlight or a description on the Unity UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are asking about [Unity Editor Scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExtendingTheEditor.html), yes there are a lot of ways to extend your inspector and even build tools inside the editor.
as for highlights, you can use the tooltip attribute of EditorGUILayout like:

```
value = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(new GUIContent("Test Float", "Here is a tooltip"), value);
```